# How to build a platform drivers into a kernel module with yocto?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, yocto, kbuild

The goal is to put an existing (in-source kernel) device driver into an external kernel module. The device driver is put together into a `struct platform_driver` instance, then is registered with `module_platform_driver()` macro. The macro is supposed to be implementing the `module_init()` and `module_exit()` functions necessary for a Linux kernel module definition, however with below `Makefile` Yocto throws multiple errors, one of them being: `aarch64-poky-linux-ld.bfd: no input files`

The Makefile:

```make
obj-m += my-mod-lkm.o 
my-mod-lkm-y := my-mod.c

SRC := $(shell pwd)

all:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KERNEL_SRC) M=$(SRC) modules

modules_install:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KERNEL_SRC) M=$(SRC) modules_install

clean:
    $(MAKE) -C $(KERNEL_SRC) M=$(SRC) clean
```

Does Yocto not support the `module_init`/`module_exit` macros? I noticed that it does compile a simple module:

```c
#include <linux/module.h> /* Needed by all modules */ 
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/printk.h> /* Needed for pr_info() */ 

int init_module(void)
{
    pr_info("My module initiated!");
    return 0;
}

void cleanup_module(void)
{
    pr_info("My module exited!");
}
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

Why would the latter work and the more recent way of using `module_init()` / `module_exit()` not? Is it right to assume that simple call to `module_platform_driver()` is enough to put a `platform_driver` into a kernel module?

Comment: I think I just discovered the error, instead of `my-mod-lkm-y := my-mod.c` put `my-mod-lkm-y := my-mod.o`. Right now, that helps a lot.

Comment: You missed `\n`:s in your strings, don't be puzzled with the messages.

Comment: It's better to use `module_init()`/`module_exit()` macros (or even `module_platform_driver()`) than reinventing a wheel.

Comment: Agreed, I had problems with making these macros work with Yocto, apparently fixing the typo in the `Makefile`  made things work.  It seems that `module_platform_driver()` indeed calls these macros and creates a module.